Why is upload speed in Tencent Cloud Object Storage (COS) when using API in cos-cpp-sdk-v5 very slow?
I am uploading a large file to Tencent Cloud Object Storage follow the document https://www.tencentcloud.com/document/product/436/14112
The steps are as follows:

Initiate Multipart Upload
Upload Part
Complete Multipart Upload

In step 2, I divide the large file into smaller parts (10MB/part), then upload each part using UploadPartData API from COS SDK for C++
qcloud_cos::CosResult result = cos.UploadPartData ( req, &resp )

The uploading is successful, however, the upload speed of most of the parts is always 0.26 MB/s.
I used the upload tool of Tencent (COSBrowser) to verify if there was any limited traffic in my region, however, the upload speed was very fast.
I also tested with MultiUploadObject API for multithread uploading, however, the upload speed of each part is also the same (0.26MB/s).
Do I need to change anything in my code or need to configure anything else to increase upload speed using COS API?
Thank you for your help!
